# Why does Virtual Box uninstall gnome-terminal?

Tags: apt, virtualbox, gnome-terminal, dependencies

For some reason, virtual box 5 after installing it from their website uninstalls `gnome-terminal`, and when I reinstall `gnome-terminal`, it uninstalls virtual box. What's going on?

Also, installing `virtualbox` 5 also uninstalls software centre.

OS is 14.04 LTS

[image: s]
[image: s]
[image: s]

Reinstalling gnome-terminal after installing Virtual Box 5.0 caused it to be removed:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
The following extra packages will be installed:
gconf2 gnome-terminal-data psmisc
Suggested packages:
gconf-defaults-service
The following packages will be REMOVED
psmic:i386 virtualbox-5.0:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
gconf2 gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data psmisc
removing psmisc (22.20-1ubuntu2)
removing virtualbox-5.0 (5.0.10-104061~Ubuntu~trusty)
```

apologies for the abominable layout and syntax, Because I do not have gnome-terminal any more, I have to use `xTerm` which is a huge pain for copying and pasting.

Comment: Host OS version? What dependency conflicts are listed on performing an install through terminal?

Comment: @Takkat N/A. Os is shown in question now, but installing  this particular version of virtual box (from their website, as oppsed to the one in software center) doesn't show any conflicts because after downloading a package from the virtual box website, it directs me to software centre page for it, and I install it from there not the terminal. When reinstalling `gnome-terminal` with `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal` as far as I can remember I only noticed the line `removing virtualbox-5` or something to that effect.

Comment: @Takkat I will repeat the process and post a screenshot of output

Comment: @Jamie please, copy the text if you're using the command line, instead of posting screenshots of text.

Comment: @muru Haha, I posted pictures just before I read your comment. One minuite, I'll post text....

Comment: Did you install the 32-bit version (i386) or virtualbox? Is your host OS 64-bit?

Comment: @steeldriver my OS is 64 bit I'm pretty sure.

Comment: But it is trying to **remove** `virtualbox-5.0:i386` which suggests you installed the 32-bit version, no?

Comment: To everyone commenting, I was very, very stupid and now realise the problem is that I was installing the 32 bit package, mistakenly thinking I had a 32bit OS.

Comment: @steeldriver Very stupid of me. I thought (until I checked for your question) that I had a 32bit OS. Problem solved :D

Comment: @Jamie Please write a short answer explaining the cause of the problem and how to solve it, so that future readers having the same issue may profit from what you learned. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Problem was caused by downloading the 32 bit version of vitrualbox from the i386 link on the website, instead of the AMD64.

Comment: You can accept this.